# How to create multiple versions of a site in django but run under same domain but different url

Tags: python, django

I have a website i developed with django and i want it to have 2 different front-end designs but same functionality. something very similar to django multi-language functionality. So i want a user to be able to access the two designs from different url by specifying the version i.e  
[localhost:8000/v1](https://localhost:8000/v1)

[localhost:8000/v2](https://localhost:8000/v2)

I created a middleware to check the current version and revert to a default if non is found. 
 **middleware**

```
class VersioningMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

def process_request(self, request):
    path = request.get_full_path()
    tokens = path.split("/")
    if len(tokens) > 1:
        if tokens[1] in APP_VERSIONS: # APP_VERSION is a list ['v1','v2',...]
            request.app_version = tokens[1]
    new_url = "v1%s" % path
    return HttpResponseRedirect(new_url)
```

and also i mapped out all app url conf using this

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^(?P<version>[a-z][0-9])?/', include('base.all_urls','')),]
```

So the problem with this approach is that all my views are expected to take an optional parameter **version** which i dont like.

So i need a better way to achieve this without having to have different codebase for different version. If i could pass the version to the view without having to specify the optional parameter to all my views, my plan is to use that version to render the appropriate template that each view render.

thanks in advance

Comment: You could store the preference in the session.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman, i know that would work without having to specify the version in the url, but i want the user to specify the version in the url.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want then. You want it to be in the URL, without it being a parameter in the URL?

Comment: i want it to be a parameter in the url without having to specify it across all my views

Comment: Guess you're looking for API versioning in Django. Here's a starter: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/

Answer (score 1):

As you said you need different versions for a frontend only and keep the functionality same.

For the frontend, you just need to change `js` and `css`

Add `"django.core.context_processors.request"` to `MIDDLEWARE` of your `settings.py` so that Django template would be able to access query parameters in request across all templates in the whole project

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    ...
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
]
```

Now in your template file, you will be able to retrieve the query parameter and evaluate directly

```
{% if request.GET.version == 'v2' %} 
    loading version two... write tags, load here css,js to be loaded if version is v2
{% elif request.GET.version == 'v1' %}
    loading version two... write tags, load here css,js to be loaded if version is v1
{% else %}
    loading defaults.. write tags, load default css,js to be loaded if no version queried by user
{% endif %}
```

your URL would be like:

**for v2**

```
localhost:8000/?version=v2
```

**for v1**

```
localhost:8000/?version=v1
```

**if nothing specified - default**

```
localhost:8000
```

**Benefits -**

- No need to write about this frontend versioning in backend views or urls file
- Only change in HTML template can allow changing the version of the frontend